# Add Parse library in Android Studio

Tags: android, parsing, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to use the Parse library in Android Studio. I added the jar to the libs folder. Nothing seems to be working without the errors of

> Gradle: error: package com.parse does not exist

Comment: What do you have in your gradle build script?

Comment: didn't add there smth. if I add compile files ('libs/Parse-1.3.2.jar) app shutdown after starting

Comment: You can't just add it to the libs folder if you are using a gradle build. Do you get an exception when the app shuts down?

Comment: its runnning for 3sec and then it shuts down

Comment: It's running now, I made a mistake at AndroidManifest, sry :)

Answer (score 3):

in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree('libs')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this solution.
1. You need Latest Android studio version (0.3.6)
2. Right Click on Your Project Folder,Open Module Settings (F4)
3. Modules->Dependencies
4. Click Add File Dependency.
5. Add parse jar file.
6. Wait for second. (Android Studio will add you library to build.gradle script)
7. Delete your build folder (TO clear cached)
8. Run It again.